# Hardware: Shortest delay to send an ouput signal using windows

Tags: windows, hardware, ports

I would like to set an output from my computer high or low. This will change roughly 5 times a second. I will be measuring the output on an oscilloscope. The important thing is to make the time between requesting the change in software and the output changing state as short as possible.  The shorter the delay, the more accurate my result.

Does anyone know which of the following options has the shortest delay in a windows environment (it **has** to be in windows)?

1. USB
2. Serial
3. Parallel Port
4. Something else?

I could try all three and measure the difference, but presumably someone else has done this already?

Thanks!

Comment: How short is short? nanoseconds?  microseconds? milliseconds?  what are you using this output for?

Answer (score 0):

Serial and Parallel will be lower latency that USB (I would expect) as the "height" of the stack between you and the port is smaller.  Measuring the latency would be challenging - how will you know when the bit of code which writes to the port is executed?

However, even with a low potential latency, the **jitter** induced by windows is likely to be quite large as well.

Vaguely related and quite interesting...
https://superuser.com/questions/419070/transatlantic-ping-faster-than-sending-a-pixel-to-the-screen/419167#419167

Answer (score -2):

USB can transmit data the fastest by far.

Comment: USB will have the highest bandwidth, but also less responsiveness because of the complexity of the USB stack. In his case, USB is the worst choice.

Comment: My gut feeling is that the parallel will have the fastest response time, with serial coming a close second. Seeing as no one has come up with a definitive answer, I'll do some tests and post the results.

Comment: Please comment the results.  I spoke with a purchasing manager of a large metrology test equipment broker about this and he said he'd go with the USB.